# Carto animation only showing data points in 1 min intervals

Tags: carto, animation

I'm trying to animate location data points, and instead of showing each point at its correct time, Carto seems to show a group of points every 1 minute (1 minute in the visualization, not real life).

My duration is set at 10,000 since this animation takes place over a 24 hour period and I don't want the objects in the animation to move too fast to be able to understand what's happening. 
I've tested with the duration set at 5,000 and it's still a 1 minute difference.

Does anyone know if there's anything in Carto that would cause this issue?

[Video of glitch](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vUNS5npkJTEYG_k_3-NeV7wcHY3FF43A/view?usp=sharing)

Here's my viz code:

```
        @duration: 10000
        @animation: animation(@timeSteps, @duration, fade(0, 2))
        @timeSteps: linear($time, time('2020-01-01T00:00:00Z'), time('2020-01-02T00:15:16Z'))
        color: ramp(@timeSteps, SunsetDark)
        filter: @animation
        width: 5
        strokeWidth: 1
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data?